# Representing bit by bit definition on XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

Here is my problem:

I have some information gathered on the "documentation" field on an XML file and I was wondering what was the best way saving these information on XML format.

I have defined new data format for my project. These data format are defined by some specific attributes and typically by their size. I first tried out gathering information about size (N-bit) for each data format and the definition of every bit in the description field, but I realized that it was impossible parsing the XML.

Hereafter an example:

```
<xs:complexType name="parameterizedDataFormat1">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="attribute1" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
size: 2 bits
00 - Func1
01 - Func2
10 - Func3
11 - Func4
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Concerning size it was quite easy, I just defined a new attribute "size" (in this case size = 2).
However, I don't have any idea how to add details for each bit signification on the XML format.

Is their any other way to put the bit by bit definition using a specific markup? Any other proposal?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation element can contain arbitrary XML; so can the appinfo element (sibling of documentation, child of annotation).  If the goal is for the information to be machine-readable, I'd put it into appinfo; if the goal is solely to make it accessible to a human reader, I'd put it into documentation.  And inside of the documentation element, I'd use XHTML for mark up the natural-language prose description.  (Not everyone does this, of course, and not all tools will do anything helpful with the XHTML.)

Comment: The goal is to be machine-readable. I've googled appinfo element, I don't get how can it be used in my specific case :/
As far as I understand, I'll get the same limitation as if information were gathered only on the documentation element.
Any interesting link or further explanation/example ? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what limitation you are encountering.  The problem I see with the example is precisely that you aren't using any markup inside the documentation element, so the task is less one of parsing XML than of parsing an arbitrary text format.  You have information you want to be able to get at; if you can think of an XML format that will make that information easy to get at when you need it, you can use that XML format inside of appinfo or documentation.  If you can't think of any XML format that makes it easy, then ... why are you using XML, again?